# iOS: Custom UITableViewCell with 3 fields

Tags: iphone, ios5

I would like to create a custom UITableViewCell with 3 fields.  I would like each of the fields to be horizontally scrollable.

```
    Field1   Field2   Field3
    ======   ======   ======
    Label1 | Label2 | [graphics: lines, etc.]
```

My question: What is the right way to implement this?

1. Do I create a custom UIViewController with 3 UITableViews?
2. Do I create a single UITableView with UITableViewCells that contain
   3 UITableViewCell subviews?
3. Other?

Any examples would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to go with Other option, with a single `UIViewController` with a single `UITableView`.

A Custom `UITableViewCell` with three `UIScrollView`s would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom TableViewCell inside that firstly put UiScrollView. inside that 2  Uilabel and 1 UiView i think(acoording to your question).off the vertical scrolling of uiscrollView through intefacebuilder. set the contentSize property of uiscrollView.be sure your widhth of ContentSize of UiScrollView greater than your cell width.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single `UITableView` with dequeued `UITableViewCell`'s that contains `UIScrollViews`, `UIlabel` and `UIImageView`'s

Answer (score 0):

Mr. nilweed. Here it will help you to add three fields in UITableView cells. I don't know to scroll the tableview horizontally.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{ 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                            reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIcon] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cellImage=[UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];

cell.imageView.image=cellImage;

UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 20)];
labelOne.tag = 100;
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
[labelOne release];

UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 60, 20)];
labelTwo.tag = 101;
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
[labelTwo release];

UILabel *labelThree = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 150, 20)];
labelTwo.tag = 103;
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
[labelTwo release];

}

UILabel *labelOne = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
labelOne.text = @"Label One";

UILabel *labelTwo = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
labelTwo.text = @"Label Two";

UILabel * labelThree = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
labelThree.text = @"Label Three";
 

return cell;
}
```

I hope it will help you a little bit.

Thanks.